# How to forbid the browser from caching the status of a radio input?

Tags: browser-cache

I have listeners on the event of radio being checked, which works perfect for the first time.

But if I refresh the page,the radio input is checked because of browser cache,and the event is not fired at all.

How to avoid this trouble?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this a lot, especially with Firefox. I'm not sure its necessarily valid but i read somewhere recently that adding `autocomplete="off"` to your form tag will prevent any form element value caching.

There is a post [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1584-Preventing-Form-Caching-With-Javascript-And-jQuery.htm) that provides a JavaScript solution that looks like this:

```
 setTimeout(
     function(){
         document.getElementById( "form" ).reset();
     },
     5
 );
```

**EDIT**

As your radio's arent in a form this should work:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar" autocomplete="off">Bar
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="baz" autocomplete="off">Baz
```

Answer (score 0):

You could propably unselect everything using javascript when the beforeunload event fires.